# Автоматическое добавление пути в хлебные крошки из своего приложения в Django CMS

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-cms

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Сделал своё приложение у которого есть категории и элементы категорий. Но хлебные крошки на этих страницах не выстраивают путь. Кто подскажет?

Comment: http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/how_to/menus.html

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev спасибо за ссылку, но всё равно не совсем понятно, не получается.